# How to deserialize WSO2 Message Broker object message queue with a Talend tJMSInput

Tags: jms, wso2, talend, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I'm working on a talend job that allows me to get the content of a WSO2 Message Broker Queue.

However, when I get the message body of an 'ObjectMessage' using the Talend tJMSInput, the result is "Not supported .."

I want to deserialize the object in the queue before call the tJMSInput component.

I have two questions,

- How can I get the serialized content of the WSO2 Message Broker Queue
  with the tJMSInput in Talend Data Integration ?
- How can I deserialize this Java Object in Talend Data Integration.

is it the right way to get all content of my java serialized object into the JMQ Queue.